# Detecting duplicates in an array using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm

I was given the following question on an exam and it seems as though it might not be possible. Is there something I'm missing?

**Given an array of n objects which can be compared only for equality, and knowing nothing about the range of values in the array, give a divide and conquer solution for detecting the existence of any duplicates in the array. This must be an O(nlogn) solution.**

We can safely assume due to the nature of the question that the solution likely has nothing to do with data structures or radix sorts, so can this be done in-place?

If so, how?

Comment: So that is _not_ asking for _all_ sets of duplicates, just _any_ duplicates (i.e. two or more objects that test equal)?

Comment: What if all elements are different. I think you'll need to check every pair.

Comment: @kilotaras is correct, you have to compare every pair and that's O(n^2).

Comment: @gbulmer Yes, we're testing for the existence of _any_ duplicates.

Comment: This would be doable if you could compare LessThan or similar I think, but not with only equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't check for duplicates in `O(nlogn)` if you can't order the items, and you can't order them if you can only compare for equality.

In fact, you can't be sure there are no duplicates unless you compare every pair, and there are `n(n-1)/2` such pairs.

Comment: ... And an N(N+1)/2-complexity algorithm wouldn't really benefit from a "divide-and-conquer" approach.

Comment: please see my answer below. I think it solves the problem accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a hashset. Add each item to the set. Then check the size. However, this is not divide and conquer.

---

Would the result of comparing for equality tell you which one of the two objects being compared were 'bigger'?

If you can create a total ordering of the set of objects, I am thinking that you could use one of the inplace divide and conq sorting algorithms but add some additional logic that detects duplicates. (turn the <= check into a < and == check)

Comment: You can only compare for equality according to the question.

Comment: My question about the equality check comes from the results of string equality checks, where the result is -x, 0, or x and allows you to create a totally ordered set.

Comment: String.Compare() is basically an implementation of an IComparer interface, which compares for relative magnitude, not just equality. Assume all you have access to on the objects themselves is an Equals() method accepting another object and returning true or false.

Comment: creating the hashset is itself requires checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is O(nlogn), basically you can sort the array and find duplicates. Since you want to use divide and conquer, I suggest using quicksort.

Comment: You can't sort the array because you can only compare for equality.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do it in NlogN time is to "cheat".

In .NET and in Java, any implementation of an interface, like .NET's IEquatable which exposes only an Equals() method, is also a base-level Object. Objects in .NET and Java have a hashing function (in .NET it's GetHashCode(); in Java it's hashCode()). So, no matter what methods the interface restricts you to, you always have access to a hashing function that will produce a numeric value.

That would allow you to hash each object and compare hashes for relative magnitude. That in turn allows you to sort the array by the hash, and then scan it in linear time to detect duplicates. You can do this in-place, or you can leave the original array intact by inserting each item into a red-black tree, hashtable or dictionary keyed to the hash value (all of which have logN or better access times and logN or better insertion times).

As stated in the comments, any of these approaches can be parallelized to multiple threads, allowing for the "divide-and-conquer" requirement; sorting can be done with a parallel MergeSort, while depending on the objects you have access to in your environment you could use a thread-safe "concurrent" collection, in turn allowing you to split the array into sub-arrays inserted into the collection by multiple threads. Scanning a sorted list can also be parallelized if you overlap the sub-array given to each thread by one element, preventing one item of a duplicate pair being in one subarray and the other in the next by serendipity.

Comment: As in Colin's answer, adding the items to a dictionary (that doesn't have duplicates) is `O(n)` and not `O(long)` because they don't have an order. So your solution is still `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Depends on the internal implementation. .NET's Dictionary uses a Hashtable, which is O(logN) insertion and O(1) access. That allows the  built-in ContainsKey() function to operate in log(N) time.

Comment: This is right but the question specifically asks for a Divide and Conquer solution.

Comment: Sorting can be accomplished with a parallelizable MergeSort, or you can parallelize the insertion into the collection by dividing the array into subarrays and using a thread-safe collection type.

Comment: Using a hash table is equivalent of saying that the items are comparable, because you can compare their hashes. Also, this is an algorithms question and implementation details should not be considered like the fact that .NET has an hash for every object.

Comment: Java has a hashCode() method as well and between .NET and Java you have the overwhelming majority of languages/frameworks covered in exams and interview questions. If this were an interview question I gave a candidate and he gave the above answer I'd consider him pretty knowledgeable in the language.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I agree, but only if testing the interviewee knowledge of the language and not algorithms. And, isn't that cheating if you tell the interviewee that items can't be compared even if they actually can be compared using their hashes? Also, would it be possible to apply your solution for the following array `[1, true, new Object(), false, 3, "a", 1]`?

Comment: If the array were of type object[] (or ArrayList), and the default hashing function in Object included the true type of the object as input, then yes. In other cases the array would not be valid in a statically-typed language (.NET's "duck-typing" is a hack that considers everything as an Object and reflectively finds/calls methods), or alternately 1 and true might collide and so an array with no duplicates might return a false positive. Most of the rest of these instances/literals would have different byte representations and so SHOULD have different hashes).

Comment: Also, in Java and .NET, Object also has a method that returns a metadata object (Type in .NET, Class in Java) that would allow you to construct a "type-sensitive" hash.

Comment: As far as it being "cheating" to tell an interviewee that items can only be compared for equality, someone who knows the language would reject that requirement as untrue if he knows it to be. If you don't know the language, only the concepts, then you would accept that requirement and say it's impossible as your answer states. I'd still give you brownie points for being able to analyze the requirements at face value and determining their impossibility, but it also tells me you don't know the nuts and bolts of the language. Algorithms in a vacuum are nice, but employers want practical results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way to consider the analysis?

Agreed, the worst case in O(N^2). But the best case is O(1).

Looking purely at the fact that there is only `equal`, and the range of values is unknown, then is it fair to say there is only one way to get N^2, and that is when all the values are distinct, or unequal?

Similarly, there would be only one way to guarantee to find a duplicate in 1 test, and that is when all of the values are equal.

There are many ways that it is impossible to have to compare all objects before finding an identical pair. If there are N/2 pairs, N/3 triples, N/4 quadruples, N/sqrt(N) sets of sqrt(N) duplicates, etc., how many must be compared before finding a pair, i.e. a duplicate?

I think this is like the 'find one pair of socks by selecting from a sock draw with an unknown number of identical sets of socks, with two or more identical socks in a set'. The owner of the sock draw restocks the draw by buying unknown numbers of pairs of identical socks, and throws a sock away when it has a hole in it. We don't know how fast the socks wear out, or how fast the owner buys socks.

On *average* wouldn't we expect *much* better performance than N^2?

Comment: Agreed; the best case is O(1) (at least the first two elements being equal) and the worst is O(N^2). But neither case is O(NlogN), and given a random set of, say, integers, you would not expect NlogN performance; you would expect *on the order of* O(N^2) performance even if what really happened in a particular case, or most cases, is more like O(N^2/2) or even O(N^2/1000).

Comment: @KeithS - I agree I wouldn't expect O(NlogN) to discover there are _no_ duplicates. But when I read the question, I still wonder if it is reasonable to assume there are duplicates, and analyse that. Then there would be 1 to N/2 disjoint sets of duplicates, and each set would contain between 2 to N duplicates. How many would need to be compared before finding one pair of duplicates. If all the values are equal, best, average and worst is O(1). If there are two disjoint sets of duplicates (size N-m and m), what is the average O? Is the question looking for an inspired, No, but if we assume ...?

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this problem with a modified quicksort.  If instead of comparing > you just replace it with equality operator. The modified quicksort will group the items together.

Then all you have to do is look for streaks to look for dupes.

Take a look at this example.

https://repl.it/@fernandozamoraj/DearJollySynergy

Comment: What is your assessment of the time complexity? Did you try to monitor `high`? How long does this take to find a single duplicate in, say, 99 million elements?

Comment: (Care to comment on [You can't check for duplicates in O(nlogn) if you can't order the items, and you can't order them if you can only compare for equality.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10128453/3789665)?)

Comment: the time complexity is same as quicksort O((n log n) + n), because it is basically quicksort plus one sweep through the array.

Comment: `it is basically quicksort` not by a long stretch

Comment: @greybeard.... basically don't assume you have values you can compare such as an image file for example. Certainly you can hash a file and then use a hashtable but the objective here is to group like items together using a divide and conquer approach.  In reality the best way to handle this would be with a hash table.

Comment: greybeard.... what do you mean... "not by a long strech"... it takes the same number execution steps as a quicksort.  It's the same exact algorithm but you use equality to group.  The purpose is not to sort but rather to group like items together.

Comment: Why the -1? IMHO this is a valid solution...Am I missing anything?

Comment: @GuibaoWang This isn't actually an NlogN operation in the average case, and his very sparse test suite hides that in two ways. First, the majority of elements in the input arrays are dupes, and second, the first pivot value (end of the array) is a dupe so he always gets one for free.

When given a properly-shuffled list with one dupe, the performance of this algorithm approaches O(N^2); only when the dupe happens to be cycled to the end of the array and then used as the pivot will its mate be found. All other partitions will not change the array and only advance the pivot index by 1.

Comment: So FernandoZ's basically turning what looks like a QuickSort into an even less efficient SelectionSort, then claiming it's still QuickSort and thus NlogN. This is a false claim and thus not a valid answer to the question.